# django Wagtail embed-videos not showing up

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am trying to make a page filled with thumbnails, and every thumbnail redirects you a page with videos added by the client himself. 
My `models.py` page :

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    main_vid = EmbedVideoField(
        verbose_name="Video",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('main_vid'),
    ]


class HomePageGallery(Page):
    vid_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+', null=True
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel('vid_image'),
        InlinePanel('video', label='video'),
    ]

class VideoBasedModel(models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePageGallery, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='video')
    video = EmbedVideoField(
        verbose_name="Video",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

I have a `HomePageGallery` page, which works fine, but when I click on it, the videos I added don't show up. 
My `home_page_gallery.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags embed_video_tags %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/css/main.css' %}">
{% block title %}Ion Matei | Servicii Photo, Video{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
        <div class="lists">
                    {% for vid in self.video.all %}
                        <div class="welcome-video">
                   {% video vid '800x600' %}
                </div>
                    {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `video` template tag is expecting to receive a value from the `EmbedVideoField`: `{% video vid '800x600' %}` probably needs to be `{% video vid.video '800x600' %}`.

`self.video.all` gives you a sequence of `VideoBasedModel` objects, so each `vid` value will be a `VideoBasedModel` object. The `video` tag (presumably) doesn't know what to do with this object - you have to pass it the `video` field of that object.